# Unable to get response of network call in a block in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am sending a network request from a  `block` in objective-c.My function is called but i don't get the response of the network call means the delegate methods are never called.I think this is the issue with thread related to it.Actually i am trying to access the contacts of user.For that purpose a block is always called.When block is called it ask user for the permission to allow access to contacts.when user press `'OK' then i am calling my custom function.Function is called but the response is not recieved & delegate are also not called.

**access contacts:**

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
{
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
        // First time access has been granted, add the contact
        NSLog(@"access contact");
        [self sample];//Here is the function i call for making network request.
    });
}
else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
{
    // The user has previously given access, add the contact
    NSLog(@"previous access");
}
else
{
    // The user has previously denied access
    // Send an alert telling user to change privacy setting in settings app
    NSLog(@"send alert");
}
```

**Function to make network call:**

```
-(void)sample
{
    NSLog(@"sample func called");
    // Create the request.
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.42/login"]];

    // Specify that it will be a POST request
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

    // This is how we set header fields
    [request setValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    // Convert your data and set your request's HTTPBody property
    NSString *stringData = @"some data";
    NSData *requestBodyData = [stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;

    // Create url connection and fire request
    sampleConn= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


}
```

Comment: **1.** Have you checked `if (!sampleConn){NSLog(@"Connection failed.");}` ?? 

**2.** Have you tried to call `[self sample]` in main queue ?

Comment: Yes in main queue it works fine.@TheTiger

Comment: Please suggest me some ideas.@TheTiger

Comment: You said it is working in main queue ... now what is the issue ?

Comment: It's not working when i am calling it through block please check my code.

Comment: And What I'm saying is have you tried `[self sample];` in main queue ? In block call this method in main queue.

Comment: sir please read my code above.In addressBook where i am trying to access the contacts my method does not works well.But in viewdidLoad it works five.

Comment: `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
        // First time access has been granted, add the contact
        NSLog(@"access contact");
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self sample];//Here is the function i call for making network request.
        });
    });`

**Try this code if doesn't work then come [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15038/ios-developer-family)**

Comment: Your code does not work for me.Delegate methods are not being called.@TheTiger

Comment: I didn't try your code yet... BUT I know that you definitely have to call your sample method from the main thread, because NSURLConnection always needs to be called from the main thread, otherwise it won't work as desired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [self sample];
});
```